# selectpicker options not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, laravel

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap-select.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/script.js') }}"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/bootstrap-select.min.css')}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}">
```

script.js

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

There are not errors in the console but options inside select tag are not showing

[image]

Comment: Is `$('.selectpicker')` a `<select>` with `<option>` as childs? -> Like in this [example](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) (see Usage) -- Try `console.log( $('.selectpicker').find('option').length );`

Comment: I've solved the problem thanks it doesn't support Bootstrap 4 and I've download a new version of selectpicker

Comment: Please answer your own question if you have solved the problem.